# No visible @interface for 'CameraTakePictureOverlay' for UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller, overlay, photolibrary

Having trouble using accessing the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary button overlay here is what I got, the problem is in the selector (takeLib:).

using property for the imagePicker

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

- (UIButton *) createGetLibraryButton {

UIImage *imglibraryPicture = [StyleKit imageOfLibraryIcon];



CGRect bounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

CGRect takePicRect = CGRectMake((bounds.size.width/2) - (imglibraryPicture.size.width/1),
                                bounds.size.height-imglibraryPicture.size.height/2-CAMERA_BOTTOM_BUTTON_PADDING,
                                imglibraryPicture.size.width/2,
                                imglibraryPicture.size.height/2);

UIButton *btnLibrary = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:takePicRect];

//using  selector(takeLib:)
[btnLibrary setBackgroundImage:imglibraryPicture forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnLibrary addTarget:self action:@selector (takeLib:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return btnLibrary;
}
```

the selector here is where the problem occurs

```
-(void) takeLib:(id)sender
{
self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{
  }];
}
```

error stated:
 `No visible @interface for 'CameraTakePictureOverlay' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'`

Answer (score 0):

From what super class did you inherit `CameraTakePictureOverlay`?
Super class should be `UIViewController`.  [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/) docs

> Present the user interface. On iPhone or iPod touch, do this modally (full-screen) by calling the presentViewController:animated:completion: method of the currently active view controller, passing your configured image picker controller as the new view controller.

Comment: The Super Class is UIView

Comment: Ok, and that is the problem. `UIView` don't have `presentViewController` method.

Comment: Try to move `takeLib` code to your view controller, and everything will work.